# Can a set have subsets of different lengths

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can a set $S$ be defined as such $S = \lbrace(x_0), (x_1, y_1),(x_2, y_2,z_2),...\rbrace$? Or should every element be of equal length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are not subsets. They are elements of the set, and can be of any length. In this particular case, the elements themselves are collections of elements, but their length is irrelevant.